# Insert the table elements in Collection

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, ejb

HI,

I have a collection and i wanna insert all the elements of my table.

How i can do this operation in EJB QL?

For example: (this isn't my code)
I have my Collection:

```
Collection<Person> coll = new Collectio<Person>
```

And i have my table Person

```
@entity
private class Person{

private id;
private name;

//getters setter
}
```

I have popolate the table and i wanna all the element in my collection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce Query in your JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "SELECT p from Person p")
public class Person {
  private id;
  private name;

  //getters setter
}
```

Then inject EntityManager in your code and use query:

```
public class MyClass {
  @PersistenceUnit(name = "MyEntitiesFromPersistenceXML")
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  public void myMethod() {
    EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Person> persons = query.getResultList(); 
    // query returns List which, in turn, extends Collection    

  }
}
```

Btw, why your class is private? It must be public.